# Till what level we can attach content page to a master page

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to know that till what level we can attach content page to a master page.
I have tried to add 7th but not succeed.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please define what you mean by "level" and "attach"

Comment: Describe your question ?

Answer (score 0):

By Google this, I got the answer.

You can attach content pages to a master page at **three** levels

**At the page level**   You can use a page directive in each content page to bind it to a master page, as in the following code example.

**At the application level**   By making a setting in the pages element of the application's configuration file (Web.config), you can specify that all ASP.NET pages (.aspx files) in the application automatically bind to a master page. The element might look like the following.

**At the folder level**   This strategy is like binding at the application level, except that you make the setting in a Web.config file in one folder only. The master-page bindings then apply to the ASP.NET pages in that folder.

Comment: Can you paste the tags required for 2nd and 3rd (through web.config) point.